# How to make X linear-gradient effect using CSS?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I was trying to make something like (the image below) using CSS `linear-gradient` (actually it's a background full-width banner) but I can't seem to figure the deg out. Can anyone help?

[image]

CSS & HTML

```css
#back {
  padding: 200px 0;
  color: black;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(120deg, red 25%, transparent 30%), 
  linear-gradient(60deg, yellow 25%, transparent 30%), 
  linear-gradient(-60deg, blue 10%, transparent 30%), 
  linear-gradient(240deg, green 25%, transparent 0%);
}
```

```html
<section id="back">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec dictum velit. Sed nec enim leo. Quisque nec urna ex. Vestibulum ut aliquet ante, non consectetur nunc. Nunc ac consequat nisl. Etiam vitae scelerisque nisi. Vivamus ipsum ipsum, tincidunt
    at augue dapibus, tincidunt aliquet ligula. Curabitur id neque porttitor, sodales velit eget, cursus mi.</h3>
</section>
```

Any of your response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `linear-gradient` and `background-size`.

You need to put together pieces. One color can be a single `background-color`:

You finally need to draw a square of any size

```css
  #back,
.back {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 100px;
  border: solid;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  color: black;
  background:
  /* red */
  linear-gradient(45deg, red 50%, transparent 50.1%) 0 0 no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(135deg, red 50%, transparent 51%) 0 100% no-repeat, 
  /*yellow */
  linear-gradient(135deg, yellow 50%, transparent 50.1%) 100% 0% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(225deg, yellow 50%, transparent 51%) 0 0 no-repeat, 
  /* blue */
  linear-gradient(225deg, blue 50%, transparent 50.1%) 100% 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(-45deg, blue 50%, transparent 50.1%) 100% 0% no-repeat 
  /* green */
  green;
  background-size: 50% 50%
}

.back {
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="back"></div>
<div class="back">test</div>
```

from your comment below, when direction is a better approach than degres.

```css
#back {
  padding: 200px 0;
  color: black;
  color: black;
  background: 
  /* red */
  linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, transparent 50.1%) 0 0 no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, red 50%, transparent 51%) 0 100% no-repeat, 
  /*yellow */
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow 50%, transparent 50.1%) 100% 0% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, yellow 50%, transparent 51%) 0 0 no-repeat, 
  /* blue */
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue 50%, transparent 50.1%) 100% 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to top left, blue 50%, transparent 50.1%) 100% 0% no-repeat 
  /* green */
  green;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="back">  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec dictum velit. Sed nec enim leo. Quisque nec urna ex. Vestibulum ut aliquet ante, non consectetur nunc. Nunc ac consequat nisl. Etiam vitae scelerisque nisi. Vivamus ipsum ipsum, tincidunt
    at augue dapibus, tincidunt aliquet ligula. Curabitur id neque porttitor, sodales velit eget, cursus mi.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, @GCyrillus! Thank you for your quick response, I really appreciate that! What I am trying to do it's actually a full-width background banner with the h3 content. I am really sorry that I didn't mention that in my question.

Comment: @Ace okay, and does it need to be a square ? have you tried anything with the bit `.back` example, inserting an h3, padding and no size ?

Comment: @Ace added an example with h3 and not squarred in answer. you can also play with it here : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MvgVwO (removed also one gradient , let you see how it works)

Comment: @GCyrillus I see some strange green lines in Chrome when you have text inside blocks. http://prntscr.com/fyuwan http://prntscr.com/fyuwf6

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov yes it does in chrome where color stop/start needs to be blurred else it is crispy , background-size makes it also jumpy depending on size to calculate 1px missing or extra (background-size can be increasedso  each pieces can overlap ) ... degrees can be be tune to avoid it a bit, direction does not leave much option .... SVG as a background would do fine actually ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Wow, you are my hero man! Just found this CSS linear-gradient was interesting and I wanted to create something but I found that that was so hard to understand, especially the deg... I'm really appreciate your answer!